# How to modify and save Rprofile.site under Windows?

Tags: r, notepad++

I wish to modify Rprofile.site file under Windows 7 R-2.11.1 using Notepad++ editor changing from

```
# options(help_type="text")
  options(help_type="html")
```

to

```
  options(help_type="text")
# options(help_type="html")
```

When saving this file, the editor keeps prompting the following message

```
"Please check whether if this is opened in another program"
```

I have no other programme opening this file.

Does anyone know on how to modify and save this file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't have write access to the program files folder. To get it on a temporary basis start Notepad++ as administrator from the right click menu of the shortcut you use to start it. Then you will be able to write this file.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is the same problem I had. It's about write/modify permission of that file.

1. make sure that windows account you use is admin
2. right click on this file and choose settings
3. go to tab security (2nd tab) and click on "edit" button (this is next to the phrase "to change the permission click on...")
4. here you need to specify which account (i.e. only your account) of group of accounts (all admin accounts created on PC) can modify this file. On the 1st tab, select "Admin" and on the tab below you can select which events will be allowed to Admin user. You can choose: full control, modify, read and execution, read, save. Put the "dash" sign to option "modify" on right hand side. Click "OK" and go back to main settings. Also click "OK" to save all of the changes.

Now you should be able to edit and succesfully save all of the changes you apply to this file.

Let me know if it works for you.